# How to make button appear on hover on lg size screens and bigger?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

The behaviour that I want is for the button with class `.bookmark-btn` to only be seen on md size screens and smaller always. But in lg size screens and bigger, it will only appear on hover. How can I do this? So far, I have done this and all works except the button does not appear on hover and I do not get compilation error:

Here is the html:

```
<button
      class="btn bg-white border-0 bookmark-btn position-absolute justify-content-center align-items-center"
      >Click me</button>
```

Here is the scss:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions',
'~bootstrap/scss/variables',
'~bootstrap/scss/mixins/breakpoints';

.bookmark-btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block!important;

  
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
  .bookmark-btn{
    display: none!important;
    &:hover {
      .bookmark-btn {  
          display: inline-block!important;
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to type in `.bookmark-btn` again within the `&:hover`. I think the following will fix your problem:

```
.bookmark-btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
  .bookmark-btn {
    display: none !important;
    &:hover { 
      display: inline-block !important;
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: be careful with your use of `!important`. Try to write your code without it, and only use it when absolutely necessary.

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Ok i made it work by adding `!important` to the `display:none;` thanks! If you could edit your answer I could give you the correct answer

Comment: I know that using `!important` is not good but the code doesn't work without it

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misspelled the classname ".bookmark-icon-btn". You should change the classname to ".bookmark-btn" instead.